# The mailman put I signed for a package I never received

Tags: theft, michigan

I was waiting on a package (Louis Vuitton Purse) I ordered 2 weeks prior. I receive the notification that the package was scheduled for delivery today between 12pm & 3pm. Than I received another notification stating I will receive my package by 6:30pm. I have been home all day waiting on this package. At 6:30pm I went to my email to track the package. I noticed I received a email at 5:40pm  stating my package was delivered and signed at 5:35 PM by me. I never signed or Receive any package. The mailman never knocked on my door. I even went outside and looked around my house to make sure he didn’t leave it somewhere. I have called and report This fraudulent activity to the Postal Service and make a police report. How can I go about prosecuting the mail carrier that lied and said I sign for this package. I am very frustrated and angry.

Comment: The whole point of signing for a package is that it leaves a record of who received the package. Track down the signature, and you'll find out who accepted your package.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus that depends on a legible signature and non-made up name.  Where I live, pretty much nothing gets signed for by the proper recipient, it’s a huge problem - I’ve come home to find thousands of dollars of IT equipment sat on my doorstep.

Comment: Yes that is, but it said it was signed by me

Comment: Arcanist Lupus is saying that you can request a copy of the signature.  Not a report saying whose name is there, but an actual copy of the signature as proof that you signed.  The signature will not match your handwriting, which will be the evidence you need to establish that the package was not delivered to you.  Effectively, when the post office says that you signed for the package, your response is to ask them to prove as much by showing the signature.  However, it may not be that the mail carrier acted fraudulently but that someone else claimed to be you.

Comment: Regardless, the shipper will normally claim insurance in these cases and send you a new package free of charge.

Comment: @phoog USPS doesn't require that the person signing for the package is the intended recipient.  I don't know who is claiming that Rasheedah was the one who signed for the package, but it may very-well be the shipper who is claiming more than they can actually prove.

Comment: Amazon delivered a package to our house.  They texted a picture of the package on our porch.  Only it wasn't our porch.  They delivered it to the wrong house.  The mailman could have delivered the package somewhere and the person just signed your name.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prosecute anyone: prosecution is done by government prosecutors, in cases of criminal acts. You have presented no reason to think that there was a criminal act, by a postal employee or anyone else. There is a chance that the recipient committed a crime in retaining the shipment, but numerous non-criminal interpretations as well. The mailman certainly did not commit a crime by delivering the mail. You, on the other hand, are on the margins of committing the civil tort of defamation by falsely accusing the mailman of lying in saying that he delivered the package to you (though because we cannot presently identify that mailman, you are safe from such a lawsuit). Saying that he *lied* is different from saying that he was mistaken in his statement. There is also no evidence of fraud by the USPS (which would be between the USPS and the shipper, not you).

Various USPS delivery methods require a signature, with no requirement other than a signature. [Restricted Delivery](https://faq.usps.com/s/article/What-is-Restricted-Delivery), if it is selected by the shipper, may require presentation of [acceptable ID](https://faq.usps.com/s/article/Acceptable-Form-of-Identification?ui-force-components-controllers-recordGlobalValueProvider.RecordGvp.getRecord=1&r=5), for example a passport. It is not a crime if the mailman neglects to check ID, though it might be against USPS policy (possibly leading to USPS-internal disciplinary action).

You are entitled to file a complaint with USPS, and their investigation might clarify where and to whom the package was delivered, but I would not count on that. It might at least clarify whether the package was shipped Restricted Delivery. You can also seek recourse against the shipper, assuming that you have a contractual relation with the shipper.

Comment: Uhm.. if the delivery requires a signature, it has to be a signature of someone at the address where the package was delivered.  Given the sequence of events described by Rasheedah, it doesn't seem like such a signature could have been obtained from anyone at that address.  Unless it was shipped, or mistakenly delivered, to a wrong address, it doesn't seem like this would be defamatory.

Comment: What thing in the description of events do you think constitutes evidence that the mailman knowingly made a false claim?

Comment: I said it was a false claim *"unless it was shipped, or mistakenly delivered, to a wrong address."*  Given that Rasheedah was at home the whole time and that no one attempted to ring the bell during the time the package was supposedly delivered, the package was either mis-delivered or the claim (that someone signed for it at the correct address) is not an error, but rather an intentional misrepresentation.

Comment: Note that while private prosecutions aren't allowed in Michigan and Federally, a few states still do allow them.